# How can I open URLs in an existing browser window with the webbrowser module?

Tags: python, browser, webbrowser-control

I’m using the [webbrowser Python module](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) to open images in Internet Explorer. Specifically, I’m using the `webbrowser.open('C:...', new=0)` command.

However, even though I say `new=0` my URL is always opened in a new browser window.

What can I do so my link is opened in an already-open browser window?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer? Have you tried `webbrowser.open_new_tab()`? The problem may be that the browser is opening the link via the default "link from external source" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try open_new_tab.

webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)

```
Open url in a new page (“tab”) of the default browser, if possible, otherwise equivalent to open_new().
```

From the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: doesnt work.  i am using ie8.  none of the commands work (ex. new=0,1,2)  all are ignored